# Append to href tags using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am learning to use Jquery and I am able to fetch data from the db inside a servlet and then send the json array to my ajax function. Now inside my ajax function, I am able to extract the values and my goal is to add the data to my href tags which is inside my  tag. Now, I am a bit confused about something- I want to create href link dynamically and append the values from my ajax to the href links. How do I go about it ?

```js
$(document).on("click", "#check", function() { // When HTML DOM "click" event is invoked on element with ID "somebutton", execute the following function...
  //event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "HomeServlet",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        console.log(value.value1); //alerting the values set in the JSONObject of the Sevlet.
        console.log(value.value2);
      })


    },
    //dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json"
  });
  return false;
});
```

```css
.vertical-menu {
  width: 200px;
}

.vertical-menu a {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.vertical-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.vertical-menu a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="vertical-menu">
    <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  </div>
  API Name:<br>
  <input type="text" id="apiname" name="apiname"> API ENDPOINT:<br>
  <input type="text" id="apiendpoint" name="apiendpoint">
  <br> API VERSION:<br>
  <input type="text" id="apiversion" name="apiversion"> ACCESSIBLE:
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="internet"> Internet<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="vpn"> VPN<br>
  <!-- 
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" formaction="Home" method="post" value="Submit"> -->
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="check" name="check" value="Check">

</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: show us what you tried, your error-logs, ...

Answer (score 0):

you can use `+=` which essentially adds to the current value. E.g.

```
var one = 'string one',
    two = 'string two';

one += ' is better than ';

console.log(one); //this will return string one is better than.
```

using `+=` takes the current value then add what's specified. So in your case, let's say your data return looks like this:

```
var array = ['string', 'one', 'string', 'two'],
    myStr = '';

array.each(function(i, v)
{
    myStr += v;
})

console.log(myStr) // will return stringonestringtwo
```

hope this makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

So the best way to do this is just make a div and give it an id that you want the code appended too and just access it's object in jquery. Ex:

Html

```
    <div id="idtoappendto" class="container"></div>
```

Javascript - Jquery

```
     $('#idtoappendto').html = `<a href="#data">Generated Html</a>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", "#check", function() { // When HTML DOM "click" 
event is invoked on element with ID "somebutton", execute the following 
function...
//event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "HomeServlet",
     success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        $(".vertical-menu").append("<a href='#"+value.value1+"'>"+value.value2+"</a>")
  })


},
//dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json"
 });
return false;
});
```

Comment: :- Lets say I have many values inside my value and I want to create as many href links inside my div tags dynamically. How do I go about it?

Comment: in value object create three inner values say divID,href,title than ` $("#"+value.divID).append("<a href='#"+value.href+"'>"+value.title+"</a>")`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/o2j5q880/

```js
$(document).on("click", "#check", function() { // When HTML DOM "click" event is invoked on element with ID "somebutton", execute the following function...
  //event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "HomeServlet",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        console.log(value.value1); //alerting the values set in the JSONObject of the Sevlet.
        console.log(value.value2);
      })


    },
    //dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json"
  });
  return false;
});

// -------- Example code ---------------
var data = [{
 value1: "http://www.google.com",
  value2: "Google"
},{
 value1: "http://www.yahoo.com",
  value2: "Yahoo"
},{
 value1: "https://jsfiddle.net",
  value2: "JSFiddle"
},{
 value1: "https://stackoverflow.com",
  value2: "Stackoverflow"
},{
 value1: "https://codepen.io/",
  value2: "CodePen"
}];

var verticalMenu = $(".vertical-menu").children();
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  $(verticalMenu[key]).attr('href', value.value1).text(value.value2);
});
```

```css
.vertical-menu {
  width: 200px;
}

.vertical-menu a {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.vertical-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.vertical-menu a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="vertical-menu">
    <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  </div>
  API Name:<br>
  <input type="text" id="apiname" name="apiname"> API ENDPOINT:<br>
  <input type="text" id="apiendpoint" name="apiendpoint">
  <br> API VERSION:<br>
  <input type="text" id="apiversion" name="apiversion"> ACCESSIBLE:
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="internet"> Internet<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="vpn"> VPN<br>
  <!-- 
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" formaction="Home" method="post" value="Submit"> -->
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="check" name="check" value="Check">

</form>
```

I have written an extra part of code in **Example code**
Explanation:

- Used a sample data
- Loop through the data & updated the current links (instead of appending)
- Example code is executing onLoad

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
data.forEach(function(i){
   $('.vertical-menu a').attr('href',i);
}
```